# curl with IPv6 proxy not working. Error: Network is unreachable

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to make an curl Request to the FaceBook Graph API in PHP. Whenever I use the IPv4 proxy it works fine. Now I started to use an IPv6 proxy to make the calls, which results in the following Error:

> Error: Network is unreachable

I think the code works properly. The error could be coming from the server, but I don't know.

I'm using CentOS 6 64 bit + nginx. Please help me, thank so much.!!

p/s: sorry, my english is bad, i used the google translator for this/mny thread.! )

- curl with IPv4  proxy (working)

PHP CODE:

```
  function get($url)
  {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Win) AppleWebKit/1000.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.663 Safari/1000.01');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '45.32.117.124');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '47876');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'SCFCFm:LSdWk1');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      if(curl_errno($ch))
          die(curl_error($ch));

     
      curl_close($ch);
      return $result;
  }

  echo get('https://graph.facebook.com/'); // show result ok
```

- curl with IPv proxy (not working)

PHP CODE:

```
  function get($url)
  {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Win) AppleWebKit/1000.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.663 Safari/1000.01');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '[2001:19f0:4401:233:c127:605a:4cc8:7c26]');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '47876');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'SCFCFm:LSdWk1');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6);
      
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      if(curl_errno($ch))
          die(curl_error($ch)); // die here , response: 2001:19f0:4401:233:c127:605a:4cc8:7c26: Network is unreachable
      
      curl_close($ch);
      return $result;
  }

  echo get('https://graph.facebook.com/');
```

Proxy Info:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRMy5.png

Comment: Are you sure the host you're running that script on has IPv6 connectivity?

Comment: HI @Pelle, how to check server enabled IPv6 connectivity ? I'm using centos 6 64bit, nginx server, php-fpm + mariadb

Comment: You can, for example, try `ping6 2001:19f0:4401:233:c127:605a:4cc8:7c26`

Comment: @Pelle still showing "connect: Network is unreachable" . how to enable  IPv6 connectivity on my vps server?